# How to Autocalculate CSS of an element

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, stylesheet

I'm not so good at css, so I would like to if this is possible.

Let's say I am not happy with the position of an element, I want to move it from left to right; however I want to use drag and drop so the stylesheet automatically updates.

I am using Google Chrome, and would like to know if this is possible via Google Chrome Developer tools, or Firefox Web Developer toolbar.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but I'd be interested in being proven wrong. +1 for the question.

Comment: i solved initial problem by 25 tries :D however, i think i really need this method if already exist.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try dreamweaver, in the design tab, you can drap items from one place to another and it'll update the html and css code by it self

Answer (score 0):

The developer tools available through the "Control the current page" icon are to analyze a page, not to change the design of a page.

You can find out which CSS rules apply at certain positions of the source, you can measure loading and processing times, etc, etc but you cannot change anything.

For your kind of problem you would need to look for a (graphical) design tool

Hope that helps - good luck